# Why you shouldn't use soap to clean a pizza stone? or some pans and pots?

Tags: cleaning, pizza-stone

I was reading answers to this question [How do I season my new pizza stone?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/how-do-i-season-my-new-pizza-stone) and many people advised not to use soap on a pizza stone, I don't have a pizza stone but I have read similar advice for some pots and pans,

My question is why you can't use soap to clean this stuff, is it just unnecessary (because a pizza stone is always in the oven and every thing on it will burn) or there is a reason NOT to do it?

Comment: my moka also says do not use soap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some cookware are 'cured'. Mostly cast iron pots and pans. I never heard of a pizza stone being cured, so I'm guessing this is to avoid eating soap. Other than that, I wouldn't know.

Cast iron gets cured for two reasons: 1. Create a non-stick layer 2. Avoid oxidation. Neither of these reasons apply to stones (or do they?)

Comment: According to [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/10726/641), a non-stick layer is indeed created.

Comment: I was told it is because pizza stones are porous, and you can season then with oil.