# how to seal a pizza stone

Tags: pizza, pizza-stone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I season my new pizza stone?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/how-do-i-season-my-new-pizza-stone)

I have a ceramic pizza stone, but ive heard it needs to be "sealed" with a coat of oil before I can use it. Any thoughts on how to do this? So far I've coated the stone with a thin layer of vegetable oil and added some garlic and rosemary. I feel like I should bake it in the oven now, but for how long? Any help would be great.

Comment: The stone is too add thermal mass to the oven (often insuficient), you do not need to put the pizza directly on it

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_5760691_use-pizza-stone-oil.html

Comment: thought it was to absorb some dough moisture leaving a crisper crust. I would never seal it... but eventually it does anyway with oil/cheese drips

Answer (score 2):

I recently seasoned my new stone by lightly oiling it and heating it at 450 degrees for about 20 minutes. The biggest thing to remember is placing the stone in a cold oven, and removing it from the oven only after its cooled back down. Taking the stone in or out of the oven while the oven is hot can cause the stone to thermal shock and break.

Answer (score 2):

Ceramic pizza stones do not need to be "sealed".  I've had several ceramic stones, as well as unglazed quarry tiles.  All can simply be used as-is.

I can be a good idea to run it through a hot oven once to burn off any chemical residue from its manufacture or handling in the factory.